# Determine 503 errors, Proxy or Application server

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

Forgive my newness, I recently inherited a couple Linux proxy servers running Apache 2.2. We recently had increased traffic to our application servers and we are seeing a lot of 503 errors.  I am trying to answer one question, is it the proxy server getting the 503 or is it the application server getting the 503? I have people on both sides pointing fingers, I would like to be able to definitively say here is the smoking gun or slam dunk why it's one over the other.  Any assistance would be great.

Comment: First place you should look into are logs on appservers and on proxies. Compare them. Generally 503 can be caused on both sides due to, say, malfunctioning appserver throwing real 503 which gets through the proxy back to the client; or, 503 created by proxy because, e.g., appserver response takes longer than the proxy is configured to wait.

Comment: We are looking at logs, we just can't find the one that points to the app server or the proxy server?  What log can tell us, it's the app or proxy throwing the 503's? I was hoping there was a log on the proxy server.

Comment: There should be a log, but this depends on your distro and on your setup. Normally those logs are under `/var/log/{httpd,apache2}` or similar but if someone configured it to log through for example syslog then they can be "anywhere", depending on the syslog config.

Comment: Our logs are there, I have been through a lot of them, I guess my question is how do I prove it's proxy or application server? The proxy logs the 503's but we suspect they are coming from the application server on the back end. What log or entry would point to one or the other. What would clearly says it's the proxy because of X.

Comment: If you have the logs, update your question please.

Comment: I clearly am not articulating my problem well. I have the logs, we are trying to determine weather the root of the 503 errors are from the proxy or the application server. The logs to us are not clear on what is the source. Our proxies are on different severs then the application. I need to track the error down to it's source, 503 by definition seem to point to the application server being busy, but I need to try and prove that.

Comment: I totally understand that. But until you actually provide the logs for me to see, I cannot do more than I have already done.